# ctrl-z to suspend vim inside of tmux not working

Tags: shell, vim, debian, tmux

So, I'm getting into using tmux, coming from GNU screen. Vim is my editor of choice. Often I find it useful to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspect Vim to get to my shell. I do this in screen easily. There I have my prefix key rebound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a SIGSTOP to Vim, and I'm in the shell. A simple "fg" jumps me back, all without leaving screen.

Now, in tmux this does not work for me. I've tried the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> prefix, rebinding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and unbinding the z "toggle pane zoom" option in tmux in case that conflicted. The only thing that works is hitting Prefix-Ctrl-Z sends SIGSTOP to tmux, suspending it, but I don't want that. I want the SIGSTOP to go to Vim.

I am on Debian Jessie using i3 as my window manager, and I can't find any conflicting keybindings, so I am open to suggestions on how to get this working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the symptoms, it sounds like you may be missing the last line in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-z
bind-key z send-prefix
```

Without it, <kbd>C-z z</kbd> doesn't send <kbd>C-z</kbd>. This is different than `screen`, where `escape ^ZZ` performs all these at once.

Comment: The last line was it indeed! I have `C-z a` set as the prefix and `bind-key z send-prefix` was everything that I had to add to my config to be able to suspend Vim.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’ve also lost the ability to zoom tmux panes.